# Error initializing Cordova: undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry

I've developed a web app using cordova 3.5.0 and it runs fine in my Z10, however there is an error when starting the app that says

[image]

After pressing OK app works fine. I cannot use Web Inspector because the error is thrown before it is available.

This is what I use to get the app up and running

```
cordova build
cordova run blackberry --devicepass 1234 --keystorepass 12345678
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution using cordova directly, therefore I've decide to migrate to webworks and problem is gone.

Migration was quite easy as webworks is cordova based, I've created a new project with

```
 webworks create myproject
 webworks pluging add org.apache.cordova.device
```

I've overwritten the entire www folder with my development, updated the config.xml

and the magic comes with

```
 webworks run --devicepass 1234
```

No initializing error anymore